# MarkLogic CPF Document read and search using REST API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have gone through the 'https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/default' to set up the pipeline to make the binary document searchable. i can observe that .xml and .xhtml are being generated out of ingested file. when i tried searching using Java Client API search query, i got the results from generated xml file rather than getting the results from ingested file.

Please let me know how can i get the uri of the ingested document while performing search using Java Client API search query. Since i want to display the actual document's content so DOC uri would be useful in that.

Answer (score 1):

Only the contents of the conversion products is indexed: the binary source file remains binary and unindexed, which is why it won't show up in your searches. If you want to get back to it, you can fetch the properties of the .xhtml document -- they will include a link property identifying the source URI. Or you can reverse engineer that URI from the URI of the .xhtml document -- the default conversion application uses a consistent and fairly simple naming scheme to generate those URIs.

Comment: Thanks for response. Even i have thought in this way but i couldn't locate the way to get the URI of document from generated .xml or .xhtml.                i got some example from the MarkLogic guide that is below,   <br/>                                                                                                  **xquery version "1.0-ml";
  import module namespace lnk = "http://marklogic.com/cpf/links" 
    at "/MarkLogic/cpf/links.xqy";

  for $link in lnk:from( "/mycompany/ankur_doc.xml" )
  return $link/@to** but i don't know how i can do this in java rest API.

Comment: you can put that code into a transform and invoke that transform as part of your search. http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_78117